# Slow meta_query with about 4 milion record on wp_postmeta

Tags: query, mysql

Although optimized wordpress all the way but still very slow
as follows :
I have converted from LONGTEXT meta_value field to TEXT
Then create INDEX for this field

```
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD INDEX idx_metavalue ( meta_value ( 255 ) ) ;
```

I continue to create FULL - TEXT search

```
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD fulltext ( meta_value ) ;
```

AND my database is **Innodb** type

Initially when the number of posts is around 150,000 posts , the query speed is relatively fast
But when the number of posts is 200,000 articles , the query speed is very slow .
Each post has about 20 custom fields , so there are about 4 million records in the table postmeta .

With the amount of 4 million records that I have used INDEX and fulltext search is not supposed to speed very slow .
But the current query very slow speed ( approximately 20 seconds )
**query:**

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_title' AND MATCH('meta_value') AGIANST('$title') LIMIT 10;
```

So how to increase the speed of queries when the query execution meta_query ( )

speed you can check in http://fixapk.com/apps or http://fixapk.com/games
Thank you !